# Having multiple errors with boolean conditions in if statements and method calling

Tags: if-statement, compiler-errors

Im having trouble figuring out some compiler errors such as illegal start to expression in my if and else statements and an else without an if.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A3Q1
{   
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Perfect square identifier (Enter -1 to quit program)");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        String squareNumStr = sc.nextLine(); //taking user input
        int squareNum = Integer.parseInt(squareNumStr); // taking string turning it into int
        boolean exitCommand = true;

        while(exitCommand)
        {
            if(squareNum >= 0) // will run method if int is a positive
            {
                perfectSquareIdentifier();
                if(return == true) // using boolean return to print 
                {
                    System.out.println(squareNum + " is a perfect square.");
                }
                else if(return ==  false)
                {
                    System.out.println(squareNum + " is not a perfect square");
                }
            }

            else if(squareNum == -1)
            {
                exitCommand = false;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
        System.ou.println("End of processing...");
    }

    public static boolean perfectSquareIdentifier(int squareNum)
    {   
        int squareRoot = Math.sqrt(squareNum); //taking square root of user input
        if (squareRoot*squareRoot == squareNum) // testing if the root provided is a root or a number with remainders
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you let the IDE you're using reindent the code so that all the braces are easier to follow? You might even find your error.

Comment: (btw, calling a variable `return` is probably not the way to go)